# Вычисление perspective

Tags: html, css, css3, математика, scss

Есть простейший блок с:

- `width: 400px,`
- `height: 100px,`
- `угол поворота: 60 градусов,`
- `perspective: 200px` задана произвольно.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility:visible;

  perspective: 200px;

  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.box span {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -200px;  
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  border-right-color: red;
  border-left-color: blue;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;    
  transform: rotateY(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** есть ли возможность рассчитать меньшую получившуюся высоту блока (обозначена красным) ? Либо, можно ли задавать большую и меньшую высоту, а вычислить перспективу и угол?

Comment: Если бы там всё вырисовывалось точно, то меньшую высоту можно было бы вычислит так: перспектива / большая высота * ширина spana * косинус угла, но на самом деле визуально угол поворота меняется в непрямоленейной зависимости от задаваемого угла, как результат, при угле 90 градусов меньшая высота достигает минимума, (и это правильно) но она ещё не прячется за ближнюю сторону спана, а продолжает разворачиваться, а меньшая высота уже начинает увеличиваться. Так что, это наверно придумали чисто для создания визуальных анимационных эффектов, но не для точных рассчётов.

Comment: @Олег, спасибо! Тоже уже поняла что вряд ли что-то получится точно вычислить)

Comment: Не понятна ваша задумка, но CSS уже умеет в тригонометрию. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cos